# crawling different languages of a page which is depending on sessions in php

Tags: php, session, seo

Hi Friends
I am sorry if i am irritating with problem.
I have a website with two languages in every page.
I mean that,the default language is swedish and if you press on eng flag it will change the session and will display in english and the whole site will run with english.

my problem is the google(search engine) is not crawling my english content.

can you suggest me some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Your site should have URLs like `/en/somthing.html` & `/fr/somthing.html` if you are  considering google to index your pages.

Comment: You will get much better SEO this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable non-cookie session id's in PHP, you will enable crawlers to follow links containing session id's as GET parameters, as well as language information. This will effectively allow crawlers to index pages in different languages.

I am not 100% sure whether Google will ignore default ?PHPSESSID=... parameter, but you may as well give it a try without altering a line of your code, but merely changing php configuration.

Parameters that control this behavior are session.use_trans_sid and session.use_only_cookies.